# Display dynamic div in front of every table in javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php

I have a table with rows which contain the Id from the database. I want that when I mouseover a particular row then it will show div in front of that row which will contain the information of that particular person using the Id.

I have tried this code but it is not fully working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc(id)
{
document.getElementById('myDiv').style.display="block";
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {

    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

    document.getElementById("myDiv").style.left=35+"px";
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_response.php?id="+id+"&myDiv="+'myDiv',true);
var id=5*id;
//alert(id);
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.top=id+"px";
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
<script>
function Hide_tab()
{
document.getElementById('myDiv').style.display="none";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
include("connection.php");
$sql="Select * from user";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
?>
<table border="1" >
<?php
while($data=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
 echo $id= $data['id'];
 ?>
<tr><td><a href="" onMouseOver="loadXMLDoc(<?php echo $id; ?>)"  onMouseOut="Hide_tab()"><?php echo $id= $data['id'] ;?> </a>
<div id="myDiv"   style="position:absolute; " style="display:none" ></div></td></tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table >
<!--<div id="myDiv" style="z-index:auto" ></div>-->

</body>
</html>
```

I want whether I move to 13 or say 14 which exist in the row of a table on mouseover, it should create a div in front of that which should show the record of that particular person.

I tried but it is not happening. Your ideas are mostly welcome.

Comment: I think the foremost problem is that you didn't understood that an `id` in HTML *should* exist only once. Hence the name `ID` for it, short for identifier. Next to that (and even independent to it), you can make use of `this` in the `onmouseout` javascript which helps you identifying the `<a>` tag you're moving the mouse out from. Then you only need to find the following sibling element with the tagname `div` to identify it. This can be done with xpath in javascript.

Comment: @hakre....Pls tell me the code...or edit the existing code.....

Comment: here id contains the value from the database and I'm passing this value into javascript using  a function and using this value as a Id which is being used to adjust the div position in front of every row. i want to upload the Image of this question but i dont have enough reputation points.

Comment: [code is here](http://jsfiddle.net/8W3L9/), I don't think the way you ask the question is well as you mix the different causes here. try to formulate what the programming question is more narrowed.

Comment: @hakre thanks for ur reply...but i already this thing, the prob is that how to create div dynamicaaly a div in front of every row when i will take my mouse over a particular row in the table. The div should be infront of every row as I already mentioned this. I also succeded in  creating the div but it is not coming in front of every row.:-(

Comment: i want to say i have to set the div margin:top value in such a manner that it will show just near to every row of the table. You will see that I tried this thing in my code. But unfortunately my output is not up to the mark @hakre

Comment: the prob is that how can i assign the div margin top value so that it will show close to every row in the table..@hakre